# Azure AutoMl error : A field of the entity is over the size limit

Tags: azure, automl, azure-auto-ml

I am trying to run an automl code on Azure using the azureml SDK (class AutoMLStep).
But it is throwing an error saying

> A field of the entity is over the size limit. FieldName=RunDto.Properties.Value/Length, Limit=550000, Size=697351
>
> ERROR - AutoML driver_wrapper script terminated with an exception of type: <class 'azureml._restclient.exceptions.ServiceException'>

> ExceptionTarget: Unspecified 2021-10-05 05:00:02.236 - WARNING - An
> service error was raised with an HTTP code 400. Error details
> unavailable. 2021-10-05 05:00:02.236 - WARNING - Encountered an
> exception of type: <class
> 'azureml._restclient.exceptions.ServiceException'>, interpreted as
> error code Service. 2021-10-05 05:00:02.544 - WARNING - An service
> error was raised with an HTTP code 400. Error details unavailable.
> 2021-10-05 05:00:02.545 - WARNING - Encountered an exception of type:
> <class 'azureml._restclient.exceptions.ServiceException'>, interpreted
> as error code SystemError.ClientError.AutoMLInternal.Service.

How do I debug this error, to find where is this error exactly pointing to?